# How to add 4 best seller item to add to cart in Amazon.com for headphones

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm stuck in automation of Amazon.com

Steps to automate :

1. Open **www.amazon.com** website.
2. Enter the text “**Headphones**” in the search box. Hit enter
3. From the results displayed on page1 add all the items marked as “**Best seller**” to the cart.

**Code** I have tried :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\****\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://www.amazon.com");
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    WebElement searchBox = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("twotabsearchtextbox")));
    searchBox.click();
    searchBox.sendKeys("Headphones"+Keys.ENTER);
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    List<WebElement> bestSellers = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[text()='Best Seller']/ancestor::div[@class='sg-row']/following-sibling::div[@class='sg-row']/child::div[1]"));
    for(int i=1;i<=bestSellers.size();i++) {
        action.moveToElement(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[text()='Best Seller']/ancestor::div[@class='sg-row']/following-sibling::div[@class='sg-row']/child::div['"+i+"']")))).build().perform();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[text()='Best Seller']/ancestor::div[@class='sg-row']/following-sibling::div[@class='sg-row']/child::div['"+i+"']"))).click();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("add-to-cart-button"))).click(); 
        //System.err.println(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//h2[contains(text(),'Added to Cart')]"))).getText());
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div.uss-o-close-icon.uss-o-close-icon-medium"))).click();
        driver.navigate().back();
        driver.navigate().refresh();
        System.err.println("try to find next best seller item ");
    }

}
```

It is adding the first best seller item for all iteration. But I want to add all the 4 best selling product to cart.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure there's no API for that?

Comment: @Filburt : Which API are you referring ?

Comment: [Product Advertising API Programming Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ProgrammingGuide.html) maybe?

Answer (score 1):

It seem like you wrong placement increase count `i`, you can try this :

```
action.moveToElement(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("(//span[text()='Best Seller']/ancestor::div[@class='sg-row']/following-sibling::div[@class='sg-row']/child::div[1])[" +i +"]")))).build().perform();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("(//span[text()='Best Seller']/ancestor::div[@class='sg-row']/following-sibling::div[@class='sg-row']/child::div[1])[" +i +"]"))).click();
```

And close button, you can use this locator :

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'uss-o-close-icon uss-o-close-icon-medium') or contains(@class,'a-link-normal close-button')]"))).click();
```

I look each close button don't have the same locator, here also has its challenges.

Answer (score 1):

In code below, [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) used to get all best seller items without sponsored(duplicates) ones. Using stream get href attribute from best seller elements. Iterating best sellers navigate to url, add to the cart and wait for a success message:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;

//...

List<WebElement> bestSellers = driver.findElements(
        By.xpath("//span[text()='Best Seller']" +
                "/ancestor::div[@data-asin and not(.//span[.='Sponsored'])][1]" +
                "//span[@data-component-type='s-product-image']//a"));
List<String> bestSellersHrefs = bestSellers.stream()
        .map(element -> element.getAttribute("href")).collect(Collectors.toList());

bestSellersHrefs.forEach(href -> {
    driver.get(href);
    wait.until(elementToBeClickable(By.id("add-to-cart-button"))).click();
    boolean success = wait.until(or(
            visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("success-message")),
            visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='attachDisplayAddBaseAlert']//h4[normalize-space(.)='Added to Cart']")),
            visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//h1[normalize-space(.)='Added to Cart']"))
    ));
});
```

Comment: @cruisepandey do you still have any issues?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem, the assignment is as follows

1. Go to Amazon
2. Search by word laptop
3. Add all results from the first page WITHOUT the discounted products
4. Go to the cart and check if the products are correct

This is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Set ChromeDriver path
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");

        // Create a new instance of the Chrome driver
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        // Step 1: Enter amazon.com and check the homepage
    driver.get("https://www.amazon.com");
    System.out.println("Opened Amazon homepage");

        // Step 2: Search for "laptop"
    WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.id("twotabsearchtextbox"));
    searchBox.sendKeys("laptop");
    searchBox.submit();
    System.out.println("Performed search for 'laptop'");

        // Step 3: Add non-discounted products in stock on the first page to the cart
    List<WebElement> products = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@data-component-type='s-search-result']"));


    for (int i = 0; i < products.size(); i++) {
        WebElement product = products.get(i);

        System.out.println(products.size());

            // Check if the product has a discount
        List<WebElement> discountElements = product.findElements(By.xpath("//span[text()='List: ']" + "//span[text()='Typical: ']" + "//span[text()='List Price: ']" + "//span[text()='Typical price: ']" + "//span[text()='New Price: ']"));
        if (!discountElements.isEmpty()) {
            continue; // Skip products with a discount
        }

        WebElement productLink = product.findElement(By.tagName("a"));
        String productUrl = productLink.getAttribute("href");

            // Open the product page
        driver.get(productUrl);

            // Add the product to the cart
        WebElement addToCartButton = driver.findElement(By.id("add-to-cart-button"));
        addToCartButton.click();
        System.out.println("Added product to the cart");

            // Go back to the search results page
        driver.navigate().back();

            // Re-fetch the product list as the page might have refreshed
        products = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@data-component-type='s-search-result']"));
    }

      // Step 4: Go to cart and check if the products are correct
     WebElement cartButton = driver.findElement(By.id("nav-cart"));
     cartButton.click();
     System.out.println("Opened the cart");

     List<WebElement> cartProductPrices = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='a-price-whole']"));
     boolean productsMatch = true;

    for (WebElement cartProductPrice : cartProductPrices) {
        String cartPrice = cartProductPrice.getText();
        boolean productFound = false;

        for (WebElement product : products) {
            WebElement priceElement = product.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[contains(@class,'a-price-whole')]"));
            String productPrice = priceElement.getText();

            if (productPrice.equals(cartPrice)) {
                productFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!productFound) {
            productsMatch = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (productsMatch) {
        System.out.println("Products in the cart are correct");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Products in the cart are incorrect");
    }
    driver.quit();
}
```

The program does not separate the products that are without discount